# QT project undefined symbols

Tags: c++, qt

After I added a class to my QT project and instanciated it, a linker error occurs.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Main::Main(QWidget*)", referenced from:
      Application::Application(int, char**) in Application.o
```

The file structure looks as follows:

```
src/
  Widgets/
    Main.hpp
    Main.cpp
  Application.hpp
  Application.cpp
main.cpp
```

The content of `Main.hpp`:

```
class Main : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Main(QWidget* parent = 0);
}
```

`Main.cpp`, with the definition that can apparently not be found:

```
Main::Main(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
}
```

It's instanciated in `Application.cpp`:

```
#include "Widgets/Main.hpp"
...
QMainWindow* window_main = new Main;
window_main->show();
```

Part of the `.pro` file:

```
HEADERS        += \
    src/Application.hpp \
    src/Widgets/Main.hpp

SOURCES        += \
    main.cpp \
    src/Application.cpp \
    src/Widgets/Main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH    += \
    src \
    src/Widgets
```

Why does this error occur? The definition is clearly there.

Comment: Can we see the full compilation command ? Did you make clean everything ?

Comment: @quantdev I `clean`ed and `built new`. This is the whole compilation output by Qt Creator: http://pastebin.com/X9iQqiwU

Comment: Have you added `QT+= core widgets` to your pro file?

Comment: @Nejat Yes, `QT += core gui widgets webkitwidgets svg`